# numpy savetxt output with E+01

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have following ndarray in python:

```
array([12.6949,  1.733 ,  7.5995, ...,  1.8878,  2.3424,
        2.8564])
```

when I try to export it with:

```
numpy.savetxt('test.csv',test)
```

the output is like:

[image]

How can I just get an output like in my python IDEA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the format argument `fmt`:

```
import numpy as np
test = np.array([1.2343251235123,3.123515236312621])
np.savetxt('test.csv',test,fmt="%.4f")
```

In this case, `f` stands for float and `.4` indicates the number of digits you want to keep.

```
In [10]: cat 'test.csv'
1.2343
3.1235
```